# BGE app doesn't work properly with eye-tracking screen recorder

Tags: game-engine, screencast

It is my master thesis project where i want to investigate the gaze fixations with Tobi eyetracker

i created everything in Blender and it works perfect but as soon as i turn on the screen recorder of eye tracker - it performs horrible, sensitivity increases 10 time and you can't walk in the 3d environment
here is the video have a look please
any ideas on how to solve this?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V3K7h8lCE3sjECoyh7WtxYG0gnwLFN4A

Comment: Sounds like the eyetracker and BGE want the same resources. Can you use a more powerful computer or run the eyetracker on another system?

Comment: but with a simple screen recorder that works great :( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mD_e6X2Fk3xR_YiL_rMvAUX4LfUVoi5o